# waitpid() function returns ERROR (-1), why?

Tags: c, linux, process, waitpid

I'm writing a Linux shell-like program in C.

Among others, I'm implementing two built-in commands: `jobs, history.`
In `jobs`, I print the list of currently working commands (in the background).
In `history` I print the list of all commands history until now, specifying for each command if it's RUNNING or DONE.

To implement the two, my idea was to have a list of commands, mapping the command name to their PID. Once the jobs/history command is called, I run through them, check which ones are running or done, and print accordingly.

I read online that the function: `waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG)`, can detect from "PID" whether a process is still running or done, without stopping the process.
It works well, except for this:

When a program is alive, the function returns it.
When a program is done, the first time I call it returns done, and from there on, if called again with the same PID, it returns -1 (ERROR).

For example, it would look like this: (the & symbolizes background command)

```
$ sleep 3 &
$ jobs
sleep ALIVE 
$ jobs  (withing the 3 seconds)
sleep ALIVE
$ jobs (after 3 seconds)
sleep DONE
$ jobs 
sleep ERROR
$ jobs 
sleep ERROR
....
```

Also, these are not influenced by other command calls I might do before or after, it seems the behavior described above is independent of other commands.

I read online various reasons why `waitpid` might return -1, but I wasn't able to identify the reason in my case. Also, I tried looking for how to understand what type of `waitpid` error is it, but again unsuccessfully.

**My questions are:**

1. Why do you think this behavior is happening
2. If you have a solution (the ideal thing would it for it to keep returning DONE)
3. If you have a better idea of how to implement the jobs/history command is well accepted

One solution for this problem is that as soon as I get "DONE", I sign the command as DONE, and don't perform the `waitid` anymore on it before printing it. This would solve the issue, but I would remain in the dark as to WHY is this happening

Comment: I'm confused due to the mixing of C and shell.

Comment: Have you checked errno?

Comment: @at77 Thanks for the advice, getting: "No child processes"

Comment: The man page says:
The waitpid() function shall fail if:
ECHILD The process specified by pid does not exist or is not a
child of the calling process, or the process group
specified by pid does not exist or does not have any
member process that is a child of the calling process.

What I think is happening is that when the program is done, and
it's status is queried, it gets removed from the list of children
processes.

Comment: As to why, see this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/414974/424512

Comment: Thanks, I was able to solve the problem by never checking the waitpid() again once it returns DONE on some process (and taking it as done).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should familiarize yourself with how child processes are handled on Unix environments. In particular read about [Zombie processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process).

When a process dies, it enters a 'zombie' state, so that its PID is still reserved and uniquely identifies the now-dead process. A successful `wait` on a zombie process frees up the process descriptor and its PID. Consequently subsequent calls to `wait` on the same PID will fail cause there's no more process with that PID (unless a new process is allocated the same PID, in which case waiting on it would be a logical error).

You should restructure your program so that if a `wait` is successful and reports that a process is `DONE`, you record that information in your own data structure and never call `wait` on that PID again.

For comparison, once a process is done, bourne shell reports it one last time and then removes it from the list of jobs:

```
$ sleep 10 &
$ jobs
[1] + Running                 sleep 10
$ jobs
[1] + Running                 sleep 10
$ jobs
[1]   Done                    sleep 10
$ jobs
$
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's actually what I understood online but wanted reassurance on that. My solution is now to add to the "job" struct and id which represents 1 if running and 0 if done. I check the waitpid() only on running elements. If the waitpid() returns DONE, I change the id to 0 and never check again.

Comment: @spano: that's a good way of doing this. You would also need to think when you're freeing your zombie "job" structs :)